# How to make Bootstrapper object of window be available for unit testing?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, express, jestjs

I have a function in my project which calls a function from bootstrapper object of window. Below is the function:

```
export default function measurement(analObj) {
    if (window.Bootsrapper._trackAnalytics === function) {
        window.Bootstrapper._trackAnalytics(analObj);
    }
}
```

I wrote below code to unit test this function in jest:

```js
import measurement from "../helpers/measurement";

describe('Test measurement', () => {
  beforeAll(() => {
    const Bootstrapper = {
      _trackAnalytics: function(obj) {
        return obj;
      },
    };
    window.Bootstrapper = Bootstrapper;
  })
  test('should send analytics object to rtrack analyitics', () => {
    const testObj = {
      pageName: "Leave Abasence"
    }
    const result = measurement(testObj);
    expect(testObj).toEqual(result);
  })
})
```

I get "undefined" for result variable that comes from measurement function call as I am unable to make `window.measurement._trackAnalytics` function available for `measurement` function at run time.

I would like to know:

1. Is my approach correct to unit test this scenario? If Yes, How to make the `_trackAnalytics` function available for `measurement` function while unit test run time.
2. Please suggest any other better approach if you know.

Answer (score 0):

The `window.measurement._trackAnalytics` function is indeed available for `measurement` function when your test runs. Otherwise, you would get a `TypeError` for calling something that is not a function.

The problem is that in the `measurement` method there is nothing being returned. The `_trackAnalytics` method is called but its result is not returned. That's why you get `undefined` as a `result`.

In order to check that it is indeed being called I would use a [jest mock function](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestfnimplementation). The test would look like:

```
test('should send analytics object to rtrack analyitics', () => {
    const testObj = {
        pageName: 'Leave Abasence'
    };

    measurement(testObj);
    expect(window.Bootstrapper._trackAnalytics).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(window.Bootstrapper._trackAnalytics).toHaveBeenCalledWith(testObj);
});
```

---

Note that your code has some problems (which I expect are typos). In the `if` condition you are checking `Bootsrapper` instead of `Bootstrapper`. And you are checking if it is equal to function instead of checking with `typeof`. I think the line should look:

```
if (typeof window.Bootstrapper._trackAnalytics === 'function') {
```